# How to programatically open a file on Editor in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, eclipse-plugin, editor

In Java, I am trying to programatically open a file on Editor using eclipse. It is important to me that the editor is instance of **IFileEditorInput**. I used the following code:

```
            IPath path = new Path(filePath);
            System.out.println("PATH:"+path);
            IFile ifile=ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(path);
            System.out.println("IFILE: "+ifile);
            //IFileEditorInput editorInput= new FileEditorInput(ifile);
            IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
            try {
                IDE.openEditor(page, ifile);
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Later at some point, I need to access the file, specifically in the **init()** method of the Editor class, as the following,

```
@Override //IEditor
    public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input) throws PartInitException {

        if (input instanceof IFileEditorInput) {
            try {

                setSite(site);
                setInput(input);    
                IFile ifile=((IFileEditorInput)input).getFile();

                File file=null;
                if(ifile.getLocation()==null)
                {
                    System.out.println("file location is NULL..exiting");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                else
                file = ifile.getLocation().toFile();
```

The problem is that **ifile.getLocation()** always returns null, and hence, I cannot access the file using **File** class. What did I do wrong? Thank You.

**EDIT:** The output of my program is:

```
PATH:D:/EbticDATA/Etisalat/Zaid/.EBTIC8/Service_Corridor.xml
IFILE: L/EbticDATA/Etisalat/Zaid/.EBTIC8/Service_Corridor.xml
file location is NULL..exiting
```

Comment: is the file already existing in the filesystem or did you create the file in your program but didn't write to disk? also from this [docs](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2FIFileEditorInput.html) i can't find the method `ifile.getLocation()`

Comment: What is the value of `filePath`? Is it a path relative to the root of the workspace?

Comment: The file already exists in the file system. The value of filePath is a file system path that is like, D:/Project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you give to

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(path);
```

must be a path relative to the workspace root of a file which exists in the workspace.

You can use `getFileForLocation` to specify a path which is a full file system path:

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFileForLocation(path);
```

**but** this will only work if the resulting file is in the workspace.

In general `IFile` will only work for files in the workspace - but you can create 'links' to files outside the workspace.

If you want to edit a file which is not in the workspace use the

```
public static IEditorPart openEditor(IWorkbenchPage page, URI uri,
        String editorId, boolean activate)
```

`IDE` method passing in the `URI` of the file to edit and the editor id.

In this case in the editor the `IEditorInput` will be an instance of `IURIEditorInput`, **not** `IFileEditorInput`.